# Variable number of method parameters with different types for each of them

Tags: c#

**Edit:**

```
func(params dynamic[] parameters)
{

}
```

lets it accept variable parameters with variable types. Ignorance is not bliss.

**Question:**

I need to write a method that takes n number of lists each of different types such as:

```
 List<Type1> list1 = .....;
 List<Type2> list2 = .....;
 List<TypeN_1> listN_1 = .....;
 List<TypeN> listN = .....;
 var result=func(list1,list2,listN);
```

but I couldn't manage with "params" keyword because it doesn't let inner functions know < T > of each list.

```
 public int func< ? ? >(? ? ? ?)
 {
      int result=0;
      ... get all lists and put them in some function:
      innerFunc(list1);
      // which is declared as innerFunc<T>(List<T> p){}
      return result;
 }
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Your problem might have a much better solution if you provide us with those details

Comment: Do the types have a common base type?  If not the best you can do is use `params object[]` or `params IEnumerable<object>[]`.  How are you supposed to know the type of a particular parameter in the function?

Comment: classes derived from strings and ints as fields

Comment: Inner functions need to have info about what is their base types (not common)

Comment: "params dynamic[] parameters" works. Problem solved. My ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The greatest common denominator of lists with different generic type parameters is `IList`

```
int func(params IList[] parameters)
{
}
```

You can then get the generic type parameter with

```
Type t = parameters[i].GetType();
if (t.IsGenericType)
{
    Type typeArgument = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    ...
```

See: [Type.GetGenericArguments Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: All Lists become IList in the end? Even when I do (an array).ToList(); ?

Comment: All `List<T>` and all arrays implement the interface `IList`. This means that they are `IList`s. `public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, 
 IEnumerable, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. See [List<T> Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Do you truly need such a function? Perhaps you can instead write a function which works on two lists at a time, producing a new list.

```
List<C> Combine<A,B,C>(List<A>, List<B>, Func<A,B,C>)
```

Then you can handle multiple lists.

```
Combine(Combine(Combine(a, b, f1), c, f2), d, f3);
Combine(a, Combine(b, Combine(c, d, f1), f2), f3);
```

Without more context I cannot say whether this is possible for your problem.

Comment: This is possible but I needed as simple as a single function instruction to try my sql accelerator using gpgpu. Takes simple table rows and outputs the count of distinct patients who have taken medicine at least once for example. It computes relations between n tables just like left join n times with a count(id).